# Error Integrating Firestore with JavaFX Maven Application (IntelliJ Idea)

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Exception occurred "com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available"

on code,

```
InputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("json file path");
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(credentials)
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
```

my pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
           <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
           <version>6.7.0</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```